# PayPal Mobile SDK authorization issue

Tags: ios, paypal

I am having an issue with the integration of the PayPal mobile SDK for iOS.

I’ve downloaded the new and latest api. Using the integrated sample for first time lookup.

Set the correct client IDs (they are correct, triple checked it).

Mock mode - works without any issues.

As soon as i switch to Sandbox i start getting these:

```
2014-07-08 19:21:05.477 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[24241:60b] PayPal iOS SDK version: PayPal iOS SDK 2.1.4
2014-07-08 19:21:06.579 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[24241:60b] Environment: mock. Accept credit cards? 0
2014-07-08 19:21:07.315 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[24241:60b] Environment: mock. Accept credit cards? 1
2014-07-08 19:21:07.766 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[24241:60b] Environment: sandbox. Accept credit cards? 1
2014-07-08 19:21:09.239 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[24241:60b] PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR - System error. Please try again later. (500) | PayPal Debug-ID: b4bbc51d2a20d [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.1.4]
2014-07-08 19:21:10.241 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[24241:60b] PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR - System error. Please try again later. (500) | PayPal Debug-ID: a5f9e9e417d35 [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.1.4]
2014-07-08 19:21:14.657 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[24241:60b] PayPal Future Payment Authorization Canceled
2014-07-08 19:21:15.634 PayPal-iOS-SDK-Sample-App[24241:60b] PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR - System error. Please try again later. (500) | PayPal Debug-ID: d1242faa1500d [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.1.4]
```

Apart from this a second question :)

The way i understand the authorization of payments is that - we don't authorize a specific payment (say the Client wants to purchase 1 ball for $4.50 - we don't authorize this specific payment - but get a generic token instead with which we can complete any future payment)?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Dave from PayPal here.

We'll look into those errors. (Thanks for including the full error message, including the `PayPal Debug-ID`!) Anytime our servers return `INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR` we are concerned -- you should never receive that one.

Most commonly, this sort of problem reflects some transient flakiness of our Sandbox server. So the problem might resolve itself before we complete our investigation of your specific error reports.

Re your second question, I have two answers. :)

1. You can ask the user to "authorize" a single payment, specifying its amount, and later "capture" that via your server.
2. You can ask the user to approve future payments, without specifying their amounts in advance.

See [this discussion](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#use-cases) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I'll check the authorization of a single payment - i've probably misread between the lines. I'll also check the sandbox payments again tomorrow in case it was something temporary.

Comment: Hi again Dave, just to ask as i am not quite sure of the status of this - i guess you guys are still working on it (still not able to complete it)? Thanks! Martin

Comment: Martin, it does indeed look like something weird was going on in the Sandbox server. If you are still seeing the same problem today, could you again please post the error message with Debug-ID?

Comment: Sure thing: `PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR - System error. Please try again later. (500) | PayPal Debug-ID: 20d8e67753331 [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.1.4]`

Comment: `PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR - System error. Please try again later. (500) | PayPal Debug-ID: ea86a9a251e06 [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.1.4]`

Comment: If it will make it easier i can give you direct TeamViewer / Skype access to see how things act for real :)

Comment: Martin, I'm asking one of our server-side support folks to take over for me on this, as they're in a better position to help you than I am. Stay tuned...

Comment: @MartinKovachev I will take a look at your most recent examples and see what I can find for you....

Comment: @MartinKovachev the errors are not matching up to what I'm seeing on our end so can I please have you file a ticket at www.paypal.com/mts with the following information and provide me the ticket number?  1) The client ID you are using.  2) Exactly what you did prior to getting the error as I'm not able to reproduce it based on the logs you provided in your original question.

Comment: PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR - System error. Please try again later. (500) | PayPal Debug-ID: baa600464ba14 [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.8.0]